# Unattended installation of Ubuntu from USB drive -- Not mounted correctly

Tags: debian, mount, automated-install, automount, usb-boot

I'm doing an unattended installation of Ubuntu-14.04-server with a USB drive on different type of servers (HP Proliant ML110, ML310, ML350).

In some cases, the USB drive is incorrectly mounted on `/media` instead of `/cdrom`, making the installation process stop with the following message:

> [ Detect and mount CD-ROM ]
>
> Your installation CD-ROM couldn't be mounted. This probably means that the CD-ROM was not in the drive. If so you can insert it an try again.

I managed to identify some cases where this error occurs:

- on the ML110 and ML310: when the hard drive is empty
- on the ML350 Gen9: even if the hard drive is partitioned.

I think it comes from the `debian-installer` that, at an early stage of the installation, tries to mount a partition from the *first drive* on `/media`. And then mounts the USB drive in `/cdrom`.

In the above cases, the hard drive is detected later during the installation process, making the USB drive the *first drive* and therefore mounting it on `/media` and not on `/cdrom`.

For the persons for which a manual intervention is not a problem, I found a workaround that I will describe in an answer below. But for an unattended installation, this is not a solution.

Can we force the installer to mount the USB drive on a specific mont-point?

Answer (score 1):

For the persons for which a manual intervention is not a problem, here is the simple procedure.

1. Open another terminal `tty2` or `tty3` by pressing `alt+F2` or `alt+F3` and press `enter`
2. Un-mount the USB drive from `/media`:

   `umount /media/`
3. Identify the USB drive `sdX` in the device list (`sda`, `sdb`, `sdc`, …)

   `ls -l /sys/block/sd* | grep usb`
4. Mount the USB drive to `/cdrom`

   `mount /dev/sdX /cdrom`
5. Go back to the main terminal `tty1` by pressing `alt+F1` and press `yes` to retry mounting the "CD-ROM".

As mentioned in the question, this is a workaround which is not a solution for an unattended installation.

Comment: Thanks for this response Jav. It worked for my netbook trying to install [BunsenLabs](https://www.bunsenlabs.org/) after creating the usb with [UniversalUSBInstaller](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) from Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue and finally by luck happened upon a set of slides that allowed me to automate this and there was an accompanying code repository with the full preseed file. https://github.com/uweplonus/adia-install/blob/master/initrd/preseed.cfg#L3

Many people suggest using `preseed/early_command umount /media/*` but this hasn't worked for quite some time due to the timing of when the preseed portion runs compared to the partitioning.

The correct way to do this is to add the following anywhere in your preseed file that is referenced by the boot command.

`d-i partman/early_command string \
USBDEV=$(list-devices usb-partition | sed "s/\(.*\)./\1/");\
BOOTDEV=$(list-devices disk | grep -v "$USBDEV" | head -1);\
debconf-set partman-auto/disk $BOOTDEV;\
debconf-set grub-installer/bootdev $BOOTDEV; \
umount /media;`